# Measurements used in Halacha

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, moshe-feinstein, chazon-ish

What is the underlying argument between the Chazon Ish and Rabbi Chaim Naaeh and Reb Moshe Feinstein? I know they argue in amounts, but what is the underlying argument? How did each get the Measurement he got, why do they argue, and what about?

Comment: The motivation for this question was theses comments made by Reb Ovadiah somthing along the lines that the Chazan Ish did not understand somthing I was wondering what he did not understand

Comment: http://www.kikarhashabat.co.il/video.php?vid=60693-56216

Comment: Warning it takes really long to load

Answer (score 5):

From what I've heard, it all starts with how you measure a "thumb-width", and from there multiply up to "handbreadth" (tefach), "cubit" (ama), and so on. The thumb-width question is whether it's measured from the narrower or wider part of the thumb.

Answer (score 2):

Another issue, though perhaps unrelated to the above opiners, is that these measurements are not stable with human appendages being a siman.  Rather, the width of an average thumb defines the measurement, which can change with changing generations.  [Rav Moshe](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=228) uses this logic (quoting the Chasam Sofer/Chavos Yair) as one apology for why the Chasam Sofer had a larger shiur than he.